# Solve name conflict in VBA Loop

Tags: vba, excel

I have a module that parses data from multiple workbooks with multiple sheets. However, while in the loop process I keep getting a message that a name already exist but whatever selection I make it keeps repeating the same message. I have tried enter a different name in the message box but it continues to repeat. Any ideas why I am getting this message?

```
Sub parse()
Dim WrkBookDest As Workbook
Dim WrkBookSrs As Workbook
Dim WrkSheetDest As Worksheet
Dim WrkSheetSrs As Worksheet

Set WrkBookDest = ThisWorkbook
FolderPath = "C:\attach\"
Filepath = FolderPath & "*.xlsx"
Filename = Dir(Filepath)

With WrkSheetSrs
WrkBookDest.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1") = .Range("A1").Value
WrkBookDest.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").NumberFormat = .Range("A1").NumberFormat
WrkBookDest.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B1") = .Range("A2").Value
WrkBookDest.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B1").NumberFormat = .Range("A2").NumberFormat
WrkBookDest.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C1") = .Range("B4").Value
WrkBookDest.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C1").NumberFormat = .Range("B4").NumberFormat
WrkBookDest.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D1") = .Range("B5").Value
WrkBookDest.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D1").NumberFormat = .Range("B5").NumberFormat
WrkBookDest.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E1") = .Range("B6").Value
WrkBookDest.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E1").NumberFormat = .Range("B6").NumberFormat
WrkBookDest.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("F1") = .Range("B7").Value
WrkBookDest.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("F1").NumberFormat = .Range("B7").NumberFormat

End With

For i = 3 To 9
WrkBookDest.Sheets("sheet1").Range("G" & (i - 3) * 56 + 1) = WrkBookSrs.Sheets(i).Range("A2:C57").Value
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: One of the cells you are copying is a Defined Name (Formulas ► Defined Names ► Name Manager). By copying and pasting, Excel thinks you are trying to create a new and identical named range. Paste the values only. Change the [Range.NumberFormat property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196401.aspx) in a separate operation.

Comment: By separate operation do you mean module?

Comment: See below for a method that does not involve the clipboard.

Answer (score 2):

One of the cells you are copying is a Defined Name (Formulas ► Defined Names ► Name Manager). By copying and pasting, Excel thinks you are trying to create a new and identical named range. Paste the values only. Change the [Range.NumberFormat property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196401.aspx) in a separate operation.

The following uses direct cell value transfer then carries the [Range.NumberFormat property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196401.aspx) across.

```
'selecting cells from Title sheet and parsing them to main workbook
With WrkSheetSrs
    WrkBookDest.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1") = .Range("A1").Value
    WrkBookDest.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").NumberFormat = .Range("A1").NumberFormat
    WrkBookDest.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B1") = .Range("A2").Value
    WrkBookDest.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B1").NumberFormat = .Range("A2").NumberFormat
    WrkBookDest.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C1") = .Range("B4").Value
    WrkBookDest.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C1").NumberFormat = .Range("B4").NumberFormat
    WrkBookDest.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D1") = .Range("B5").Value
    WrkBookDest.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D1").NumberFormat = .Range("B5").NumberFormat
    WrkBookDest.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E1") = .Range("B6").Value
    WrkBookDest.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E1").NumberFormat = .Range("B6").NumberFormat
    WrkBookDest.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("F1") = .Range("B7").Value
    WrkBookDest.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("F1").NumberFormat = .Range("B7").NumberFormat

End With

For i = 3 To 9
    WrkBookDest.Sheets("sheet1").Range("G" & (i - 3) * 56 + 1) = WrkBookSrs.Sheets(i).Range("A2:C57").Value
Next
```

Comment: Something like this? I edited trying to use direct value transfer. See above

Comment: I'm not sure why you copied my code into your original question but yes, direct value transfer and carrying the number format(s) across does not involve the clipboard so not attempt to replicate a defined name is made.